# Broadcast a message from a background job so that it appears on all sessions including the login screen

Tags: hdmi, login

I'm running a python program as a background job, started by systemd on boot.

From this background job, I would like to print messages to the login screen
(the screen that's visible on the HDMI output and waiting for the pi user
login)

The reason: In a situation with no network, no wifi and no keyboard connected,
the easiest way to check that this job is running is to hook up the pi to
an HDMI input.

Any simple way to do this?

Comment: First thought would be to try sending message to /dev/tty0 - second thought is to flash an L.E.D. on a GPIO port while the job is running.  I would be tempted to use a multi-colour LED so you can show the job status...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its more general Linux than Pi and should be on the Linux exchange as per https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in `-n` and `-l` options of [`getty`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/util-linux/getty.8.en.html):

> -l, --login-program login_program
> Invoke the specified login_program instead of /bin/login. This allows the use of a non-standard login program (for example, one that asks for a dial-up password or that uses a different password file).

> -n, --skip-login
> Do not prompt the user for a login name. This can be used in connection with the -l option to invoke a non-standard login process

Your script would be such a "non-standard login program" that occupies an unused terminal without actually checking for username/password.

Make sure not to start it on *every* terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `StandardOutput` option in `man systemd.exec`:

> StandardOutput=
>
> Controls where file descriptor 1 (STDOUT) of the executed processes is connected to. Takes one of inherit, null, tty, journal, kmsg, journal+console, kmsg+console, file:path, append:path,
> socket or fd:name.
>
> [...]
>
> **journal+console** and **kmsg+console** work in a similar way as the two options above but copy the output to the system console as well.

The "two options above" are `journal` and `kmsg`, which are explained there if the general meaning isn't self-evident.  There does not appear to be a `console` alone option; probably you want `journal+console`.

There's also a `tty` option which might work for this purpose but will be less robust.  What you want is the system console (which usually runs on a tty device, but exactly which one is not determinable in this context, I think).

If you'd rather use stderr, use `StandardError=` instead (or as well as if you want both). If you are looking for an index to all the directives, there's `man systemd.directives` (there's also `man systemd.index`, but it is not the same thing).

This doesn't meet the stipulation:

### ...so that it appears on all sessions

Eg., it won't cover ssh logins, or logins not on the tty that's the system console.  The canonical method of doing that would be to use `wall`; from `man wall`:

> `wall` displays a message, or the contents of a file, or otherwise its standard input, on the terminals of all currently logged in users.

You'll have to wrap your program execution in a shell script for that (something very short that pipes to `wall`<sup>1</sup>.  You could incorporate it directly into the python but the more appropriate way to do that would be to use some kind of POSIX module that wraps this or otherwise provides the means (eg., output to a tty, although you can do this by directing to a `/dev/` node).

---

1. You might instead be able to do something with the `StandardOutput` directive, have a look at the `file` or `fd` options, but I think it may be a little convoluted without a wrapper.